# Android Studio NDK return jint

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have successfully followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ to learn about building NDK apps with Android Studio.

That tutorial uses a `public native String HelloJNI();`

That string is set in the `HelloJNI.c` file

```
#include "com_example_myapplication_MainActivity.h"
/* Header for class com_example_myapplication_MainActivity */

/*
 * Class:     com_example_myapplication_MainActivity
 * Method:    HelloJNI
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_HelloJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from jni");
}
```

and loaded at runtime with

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");
    }
```

Now Im attempting to do the same thing but retrieve and `int` not a `string`
`public native int getintONE();`

I follow the same steps in the tutorial, everything works fine, now my `getintONE.c` reads

```
#include "com_example_myapplication_MainActivity.h"
/*
 * Class:     com_example_myapplication_MainActivity
 * Method:    getintONE
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_getintONE
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
```

What is the equivelant of

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_HelloJNI
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
(*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from jni");
}
```

To return an int, not a string.

I've read through many questions here, read tutorial and documentation, most of the stuff I've seen on my research and tried were samples for returning, jint arrays, converting jint to string, and what seem to me to be more involved advanced topics.

Thanks in advance

Comment: well just return it?

Comment: so how would I return it without doing `return 1; `
If I wanted to return a variable from a shared library..thanks

Comment: jint a = 2; return a;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jint is a primitive type, so if you have included `jni.h` you can simply return one from the function - there is no need to allocate an Object as you were doing with NewStringUTF() for a String.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_getintONE(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
      return 1;  //or anything that can be cast to a jint
}
```

Comment: if i want to create a integer variable inside this method how to do.For example string variable hello:
jstring
Java_com_myndkapp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}